# prop dynmacially linked to component becomes undefined after being changed in child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

So I have this issue with a component used to login with github.

I'm linking a variable named `username` to the component, so that once the component finishes its job logging in the user, it would update the username into that variable, so it could be used by the app elsewhere.

I have done so like this:

In App.vue

```
<other app tags....>
<SignInWithGithub
  github_clientid="5c6f1bd40f1841f1674a"
  v-bind:username_object="username"/>
<other app tags....>
```

and it's being initialized with `null` in App.vue:

```
data () {
  return {
    username: null
  }
}
```

In the component `SignInWithGithub`:

```
mounted () {
  console.log("in child: " + this.username_object) //null
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log("in child: " + this.username_object) //undefined
  },2000)
  this.checkLogin()
},
props: [
  'github_clientid',
  'username_object'
],
methods: {
  checkLogin: function() {
    fetch('/whoami', {credentials: 'same-origin'})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(({logged_in, github_userid, github_username}) => {
       if(logged_in) {
         this.show_login_button = false;
         this.github_login_link = null;
         this.github_userid = github_userid;
         console.log(this.username_object) //null
         this.username_object = github_username;
         console.log(this.username_object) //tomklino
       } else {
         this.show_login_button = true;
       }
     })
  }
},
```

In the component, in the `checkLogin` function, I get the value I expect when I assign it, but once it's done, the value becomes undefined and I don't understand why.

any insights on what I might have missed?

Comment: if you `console.log(this)` in your fetch function is it the vue instance or the fetch instance? I know if you have a jQuery function for example and you want to assign a variable back to your vue data you need to have a `var self = this` before the function and in the function `self.username_object = github_username`

Comment: You're changing the value of a property `username_object` in a child component which is a no no in Vue. The the parent re-renders, the component will lose whatever value it has and be updated with the value from the parent. If you want to change the `username_object` value, you should emit the value to the owner of the data and let it update the data. If you are using the development version of Vue, there will be a warning in the console about this.

Comment: Thank you @bert. That solved my problem. You can include this as an answer if you like, I'll accept it